# Running out of memory using FindMinimum with ParametricFunctions

Tags: memory

I am running a pretty large optimization problem which actually consists of an outer an inner optmization problem. I use ParametricNDSolve for solving a ODE system. When the optimization is done, Mathematica uses almost all of my RAM memory. If I try Remove["Global`*"] the memory used is still the same.

Is there an easy way to check where the RAM in used?

Comment: Does setting `$HistoryLength=0` help?

Comment: What happens when you quit the kernel?

Comment: $HistoryLength=0 does not solve the issue..When I quiet the kernel the RAM used is decreased to the amount that is used when Mathematica is started.

Answer (score 2):

I used to have the same problem.

It would've helped if you had posted your code here. Anyways I had the same problem and I completely solved it by changing the method.
try all of these methods see which one suits your problem more

- TimeIntegration
- BoundaryValues
- DiscontinuityProcessing
- EquationSimplification
- IndexReduction
- DAEInitialization
- PDEDiscretization

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: The problems is pretty large, but I will try to create a small example to illustrate the problem..

I will take a deeper look at the methods you mentioned and see if it helps!

Comment: I haven't found any solution to the problem above. Is anyone aware of problems with NDSolve and memory management? I call NDSolve inside a Module which is called several times during the optimization. When the optimization is done a large amount of memory has disappeared somewhere. It's not in the global context since I dont free up the memory when Removing the global context.